# Legend not showing. Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: legend

I have the code below that is a combination of two boxplots and dot plots in one. It is a representation of barring density in 4 different species. The grey depicts the males and the tan the females.

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/A_Trogon rufus/Black-and-White/BARDATA_boxplots_M.csv")
datF<-read.csv("C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/A_Trogon rufus/FEMALES_BW&Morphom.csv")
cleandataM<-subset(data, data$Age=="Adult" & data$White!="NA", select=(OTU:Density))
cleandatF<-subset(datF, datF$Age=="Adult", select=(OTU:Density))
dataM<- as.data.frame(cleandataM)
dataF<- as.data.frame(cleandatF) 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataM, aes(factor(OTU), Density))+ 
geom_boxplot(data=dataF,aes(factor(OTU),Density), fill="AntiqueWhite")+
geom_boxplot(fill="lightgrey", alpha=0.5)+
geom_point(data=dataF,position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), colour="tan")+
geom_point(data=dataM, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1),   color="DimGrey")+ scale_x_discrete(name="",limits=order)+
scale_y_continuous(name="Bar Density (bars/cm)")+
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black", size=14),
axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=12),
axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=14))
```

This works just fine.

However, when I try to add a legend as:

```
legend("topright", inset=.01, bty="n", cex=.75, title="Sex",
c("Male", "Female"), fill=c("lightgrey", "black")
```

It returns the following Error:

Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

Please, is there someone who could suggest how to correct this?